# Buscar en un string letras que aparezcan tanto en mayúscula como en minúscula

Tags: javascript, regex

Tuve un desafío hace poco y me pidieron devolver la mayor letra (alfabéticamente ordenada, por ejemplo entre la `b` y la `z`, devuelvo la `z`) tal que, dado un `string`, aparezca tanto en mayúscula como en minúscula.

Lo hice de la siguiente forma

```
function solution15(S) {
    const arr = S.split("");
    const lowercase = arr.filter((a)=> a === a.toLowerCase());
    const uppercase = arr.filter((a)=> a === a.toUpperCase());
    const coincidences = uppercase.filter(val => lowercase.includes(val.toLowerCase()));
    if (coincidences.length) {
        coincidences.sort();
        return coincidences[coincidences.length-1];
    }
    return "NO";
}
```

Lo cual funciona pero con bajo rendimiento. 
No se me ocurre otra solución que sea mejor pero entiendo que las hay. Se puede hacer con *regex* por ejemplo?

Gracias!

Comment: Buscar bajo que idea?, es decir todas las que aparezcan tanto en mayúscula así como minúscula?

Comment: Ahi aclare! es solo la mayor, no todas. Gracias por la observacion

Comment: Si quieres probar con expresiones regulares, puedes mirar esto https://regex101.com/

Comment: Por qué dices que funciona con bajo rendimiento? Qué métricas has usado?

Comment: Julio, yo ninguna, pero desde la pagina de Codility me salio una performance del 9% para ese algoritmo lo cual es muy malo jaja pero no se me ocurre como mejorarlo

Answer (score 0):

Primero decir que no creo que necesites ninguna optimización, salvo que sea un proceso crítico.

Además, la medida de 'rendimiento' que aportas, en base aun porcentaje no dice mucho por si misma. Lo que sería útil es mirar cúanto **tiempo** tarda en ejecutar varios casos de pruebas, y en base a eso decidir si realmente se necesita optimizar (muy probablemente no)

Dicho lo cual, optimizarlo como ejercicio puede ser interesante.

Esta alternativa es alrededor de un 40% más rápida que la del enunciado para strings *grandes* (Tienes benchmarks en esta [url](https://jsbench.me/1xk7gj35sd/1))

La diferencia entre las dos soluciones crecería con strings más grandes y se iría reduciendo a medida que los strings sean más cortos.

```js
function invierte(letra) {
    return letra.toUpperCase() == letra
    ? letra.toLowerCase()
    : letra;
}

function solution15(S) {
  const visitadas = {};

  const encuentra_desde = (letra, idx) => {
    for (var i = idx; i < S.length; i ++) {
      if (letra == S.charAt(i)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < S.length; i ++) {
    const letra = S.charAt(i);
    if (visitadas[letra.toUpperCase()] === undefined) {
        visitadas[letra.toUpperCase()] = encuentra_desde(invierte(letra), i + 1);
    }
  }

  const finales = Object.keys(visitadas).sort().reverse();
  for (var i = 0; i < finales.length; i ++) {
    if (visitadas[finales[i]]) return finales[i];
  }
  return "NO";
}

console.log(solution15('abracadabraRZ'));
```

La idea básicamente es evitar la manipulación y acceso a memoria lo máximo posible.

Para ello evitamos crear esos dos arrays que creas en tu solución, siempre trabajaremos con el string original obteniendo los caracteres usando `charAt`

Además, lo recorremos de manera más eficiente:

- Primeramente llevamos un registro de las letras que hemos examinado. Cuando examinamos una letra, guardamos el resultado de si existe o no la contraria. Una vez se ha examinado una letra, no tiene sentido volver a examinarla otra vez.
- Además, cuando miramos si existe la letra contraria, lo hacemos a partir de la posición de la letra actual. No tiene sentido mirar desde el inicio del string porque ya hemos examinado esa parte.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let str = "aZb";
let res = str.slice(0,1);
for(let i = 0; i< str.length; i++){
  aux = str.slice(i,i+1);
  if ( res.toLowerCase() < aux.toLowerCase() ){
    res = aux;
  };
};
console.log(res);
```

Te dejo por aqui lo que se me ocurrio, recorro el string y si la letra nueva que encuentro es mas grande que el actual res las cambio, te sugiero pasar el string "str" a lowercase asi cubris todos los casos posibles espero te sirva.

Comment: No cumple con lo de: `tal que, dado un string, aparezca tanto en mayúscula como en minúscula. `

Comment: ahi lo edite, no era muy complicado de arreglar. Ademas aclare en la descripcion de abajo

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Tomas! pero lo que hace esto es devolverme la letra mas grande del alfabeto dentro del string, sin importar si es mayuscula o minuscula. Lo que yo busco es que me devuelva la mas grande del string que aparezca tanto en mayuscula como en minuscula.
Por ejemplo si coloco
'aaAbbBc' 
tu algoritmo me devuelve c
y en realidad deberia devolverme b.
Espero haberme explicado y gracias!